# Interrupt a button through a service

Tags: android

my question is, can a service that is running in the background actually interrupt a button after it is clicked?
For example, if i use my home button to enable Google assistant (keep holding the home button for 2-3 seconds) my service pops up before the Google assistant starts up and ask for an authentication password which obviously has been set before the service gets installed, 
If it is possible could you provide me a useful guide?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use an ontouchlistener or a onlongclicklistener. This way, after a couple seconds of holding down the button an action or interupt can be performed. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html